# GithubPages not displaying images/videos online but displays locally

Tags: html

my github repo is this: https://github.com/Snipervuk/ChristianMilicevic

My HTML images or videos won't display on my github pages online, but do display locally.

I have tried doing the following solutions :

- ./images/ImageName.png
- ./images/ImageName.PNG
- images/ImageName.png
- images/ImageName.PNG

etc

So if someone could tell me what im doing wrong that would be great...

Thanks

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead. Stackoverflow does support [inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a base href inside the head tag
like,

```
<head>
...
<base href="http://www.christianmilicevic.com/">
...
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

All good solved it was assets/css/ThenImagename, thanks